# How to Extract HTML using XPath like YQL using php?

Tags: php, json, xml, xpath, yql

I am using YQL (https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) but Per application limit (identified by your Access Key): 100,000 calls per day and Per IP limits: /v1/public/*: 2,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/*: 20,000 calls per hour .

I need unlimited query. How to Extract HTML using XPath like YQL using php.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://google.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($homepage);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach($xpath->evaluate('div') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
var_dump($result);
```

I just found this example from web but not working.

**Edit**

```
    $homepage = file_get_contents('https://google.com');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($homepage);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $result = '';
    foreach($xpath->query('//a[@class="touch"]') as $childNode) {

      // if output <a class="touch" href="url"><span alt="demo1" title="title2">Content</span> some</a> , How to get href/url and child tag span  attribute alt/title ? 

      $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
    }
    var_dump($result);
```

If possible then how to extract full HTML to json/xml like yql using php?

Comment: Use $xpath->query() to fetch the desired nodes.

Comment: See updated Question @Borna

Comment: I see nothing new ^^

Comment: I need output like yql(json/xml). How to get that?

Comment: Why do you need it in json? can't you just parse the dom to get specific data?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: to get href from <a>, use $childNode->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue; inside your foreach loop. But, to get data that is inside of <a>, you'll need further processing.

Comment: btw, don't use DOMNodeList inside foreach loop becuase your intellisense is probably not working in your IDE, rather use normal for loop because DOMNodeList has lenght and item property, and therefor you'll see possible functions for DOM object.

Comment: I just changed it to `$childNode->getAttribute("href");` and now working but i have more tags under `a` tag like `span` but how to get their attribute? Can you give an example?

Comment: But i just asking can i extract full HTML to json/xml?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do further processing, one is by doing another query. To get the span node, use can use this query:

```
$span = $xpath->query('./span', $childNode); // all spans
$span->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem("alt")->nodeValue; // first span
```

What you are doing is searching under the given node.

p.s. don't use attributes property as an array (attributes["attributeName"]) because it doesn't work in some versions of PHP.